# n! v.s. $a^{n}$ How can we know which one is faster without graphing?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

n! v.s. $a^{n}$ If we are given an arbitrary number a (a>1). How can we know which one is faster as n->INFINITY without graphing?

Comment: hint: consider the function $f(n) = \frac{n!}{a^n} = \frac{1}{a}\cdot \frac{2}{a}\cdot\frac{3}{a}\dots\frac{a}{a}\dots\frac{2a}{a}\dots\frac{n}{a}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n \rightarrow \infty$, $n!$ is always going to win. We have

\begin{align*}
\frac{a^n}{n!} & = \frac{a}{1} \frac{a}{2} \ldots \frac{a}{n-1} \frac{a}{n}
\end{align*}

Now, let $N$ be the smallest integer that satisfies $N \geq a$. Furthermore, let $n > N$. We have

\begin{align*}
\frac{a^n}{n!} & = \underbrace{\frac{a}{1} \frac{a}{2} \ldots \frac{a}{N-1}}_{>1} \times\underbrace{\frac{a}{N} \frac{a}{N+1} \ldots \frac{a}{n-1} \frac{a}{n}}_{<1}
\end{align*}

where the tail becomes smaller and smaller for increasing $n$. You can now verify that the tail of this product 'overwhelms' the head for $n$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out Sterling's approximation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 0):

Of the $n$ factors in $n!$, half are bigger than $\frac n2$, so
$ n! \ge (\tfrac n2)^{n/2} = \left(\sqrt{\tfrac n2}\right)^n >\!\!> a^n $, because $\sqrt n >\!\!> a$.